# Declaring a function in firebase realtime rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I use **firebase realtime** as database for my app 
and off course i used rules to secure my data 
so more node database then more rules and now have a big code inside it

my question is about how to define function to make my rules more readable  and make it less code

I would to get like  this

```
"rules": {

           function isMerchant(auth){
             return "root.child('Merchant').child(auth.token.phone_number).exists()";
           }

           "UsersMetaData" :{
                    "HistoryMarketVisit":{
                      "$visitId":{
                        ".read" :  isMerchant(auth),
                        ".write" :  isMerchant(auth),
                      }
                    },

              },
    },
```

i see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442795/declaring-a-function-in-firestore-rules) answer for same question but is for **firestore** , but want to achieve it in **firebase real time**

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

As Doug also answered, the Firebase Realtime Database security rules don't natively have support for declared functions in there.

What you can do however is use Firebase's [Bolt security modeling language and compiler](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt). Bolt does support callable functions, by expanding them in the way you'd otherwise do manually, and has many other nifty features.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Realtime Database rules don't have support for custom functions like you see in Firestore.  You will have to duplicate the logic wherever it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for answer, really this is bad and was supposed to be supported.
When you have a large database, it will be really difficult readable or easy to update rules